# pattern matching check if greater than symbol is not preceded by smaller than symbol

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

i would like to check if the greater sign is preceded by the smaller than sign.
what i really need is to check i there are more than one word seprated by space between the > and <.

for example :

```
<a v >
```

should be found because there are more than one "word" inside

and this :

```
< a >
```

should not

here is my python code

```
text = '<a > b'
if re.search('(?<!\<)[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+>',text):   # search for '>'
   print "found a match"
```

for this text i dont want it to match because there is a smaller than sign before.
but it does find a match. 
the [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) does not seem to be working.

**solution(kindof):** 
this also finds smaller than symbol that is not preceded by a greater than symbol

```
match = re.search('<?[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+>',text)
if ((match) and (match.group(0)[0] != '<')):
   print "found >"
match = re.search('<[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+>?',text)
if ((match) and (match.group(0)[len(match.group(0))-1] != '>')):
   print "found <"
```

thanks homson_matt for the solution.

**BETTER SOLUTION:**

by replacing the string that causes the problem before looking for the greater and smaller symbols.

```
# replace all templates from source hunk ( <TEMPLATE> )
srcString = re.sub("<[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\*:/\.]+[ ]*>", "TEMPLATE", srcString)
if re.search('[a-zA-Z0-9_ )]>',srcString): # search for '>'
    return True
if re.search('<[a-zA-Z0-9_ (]',srcString): # search for '<'
    return True
```

Comment: `search` searchers for a position in the string where the expression matches. ` >` matches. Do you just want to verify that there is no `< >` sequence in your text?

Comment: yes but a sequence like this:  'x < 5 and y >5' is good tough

Comment: if there is only one word between them it should not find it, if more than one word than it should

Comment: Although this doesn't fix the issue, note that `'(?<!\<)[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+>'` pattern should be `re.search('(?!<\<)[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+>',text)` i.e. the `!` character goes before the `<` character.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: No, `(?<!\<)` is correct.  The only thing wrong with it is the unnecessary backslash, but that doesn't hurt anything.  `(?!<\<)` is a negative **lookahead** for `<<`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The match is: `a >`.  This section matches your regex perfectly - it doesn't start with <, then it's got "a ", which matches the bit in square brackets, and then there's a >.

Are you trying to match the whole string? If you are, try `re.match` instead of `re.search`.

Or you might want to try this code.  It searches for a substring that might start with <, and then decides if it actually does.

```
text = '<a > b'
match = re.search('<?[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+>',text)

if ((match) and (match.group(0)[0] != '<')):
  # Match found
```

Comment: yeah this one is pretty good. btw how do i check if the string dont end with a '>' sign

Comment: and how can i make sure i only check in current line if there is a < in the begining

Comment: The match is `'a >'` only because yossi entered an incorrect negative lookbehind assertion. If it was entered correctly as `'(?!<'`, then the match would be `' >'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
r'<\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)+\s*>'
```

`\w+` matches the first word, then `(?:\s+\w+)+` matches one or more additional words, separated by whitespace.  If you don't want the match to span multiple lines, you can change `\s` to a literal space:

```
r'< *\w+(?: +\w+)+ *>'
```

...or to a character class for horizontal whitespace only (i.e., TAB or space characters):

```
r'<[ \t]*\w+(?:[ \t]+\w+)+[ \t]*>'
```

Comment: thanks,but i need it to find even if only one is present like this: x> 5

Comment: Are you trying to parse Boolean expressions with regexes?

Comment: i just want to find if they are there. and ignore templates (C++)